# Using jQuery to change PHP variable content without refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a multi-language website – English and German.

I have a file `content.php` in which my English and German content is stored.

Here’s an example:

```
  $content_en = array(
    'title'       => 'title',
    'type'        => 'photography',
  );

  $content_de = array(
    'title'       => 'titel',
    'type'        => 'fotografie',
  );
```

In my `index.php` I get the values like this:

```
  // Checking for browser default language
  $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

  // Storing browser default language in variable – either `$content_en` or `content_de`
  $content_lang = ${ 'content' . '_' . $lang };

  // Output title in browser default’s language
  echo $content_lang['title'];
```

But I also like to have a language switcher on my site in case the browser default language is not the correct one:

```
<button class="lang-en">EN</button>
<button class="lang-de">DE</button>
```

Now I’d like to change the variable `$lang` depending on which button is clicked in either `en` or `de`. The important part is: I like the values to change WITHOUT page refresh.

I know the following code does not work like this but it literally describes what I like to achieve:

```
  $(' .lang-en' ).click( function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $lang = 'en';
  });
  $(' .lang-de' ).click( function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $lang = 'de';
  });
```

I am not sure if it is somehow possible (e.g. with ajax) but maybe somebody has a clue to solve my problem.

Many thanks!

Comment: First off, since PHP is a serverside language, and the PHP file is not persistent, changing the variable will be pointless because it has already loaded. You need to change the actual datastore weather it is a DB or file based. Second; according to your example, $lang is a JS variable, not a PHP one. In this case you must simply expand the scope of $lang so it can be accessed by your functions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I am aware of that problem with PHP being serverside. Thanks also for the hint with expanding the scope of `$lang`. Can you help out with some more details?

Comment: You should mark it as global.

Comment: FYI, Google provides a fantastic hasslefree language switcher that uses their API and doesn't even require you to keep language files. https://inputmapper.com example of in use on one of my sites (top right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request your php page via ajax.

```
var content;
 $.ajax({
    url: "yourServerUrl/getLang.php?lan=en", 
    success: function(result){
            content = result;
        }
  });
```

Now this content must have the object returned by your getLang.php

getLang.php can be as follows.

```
<?php

  $content_en = array(
    'title'       => 'title',
    'type'        => 'photography',
  );

  $content_de = array(
    'title'       => 'titel',
    'type'        => 'fotografie',
  );

if($_GET["lan"]=="en"){
echo json_encode($content_en);
}
else{
echo json_encode($content_de);
}
```

So now on your button click, you can call php as

```
$(' .lang-en' ).click( function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    url: "yourServerUrl/getLang.php?lan=en", 
    success: function(result){
            content = result;
        }
  });
    $lang = 'en';
  });


  $(' .lang-de' ).click( function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    url: "yourServerUrl/getLang.php?lan=de", 
    success: function(result){
            content = result;
        }
  });
    $lang = 'de';
  });
```

Now lets assume that you will have 2 tags, saying `<h1 id="title"></h1>`
and `<h2 id="type"></h2>` on your page to display the text.

So, your ajax call shall be modified as shown below..

```
$.ajax({
    url: "yourServerUrl/getLang.php?lan=en", 
    success: function(result){
            content = result;
            $("#title").text(content.title);
            $("#type").text(content.type);

        }
  });
```

This would automatically get your text to correct places and with correct language as required.

Comment: Many thanks! So what I did now is to add your jQuery snippet and created a file named `getLang.php` containing the code you wrote. What I now get when clicking on either the English or German buttons is the content of `getLang.php` in either English or German as JSON. How do I now get these data into to right places on the Website?

Comment: alright... I am updating my answer again..@user1706680

Comment: check the answer now @user1706680

Comment: Thanks! I get the error that `content.title` is undefined. Besides: Is there a away to echo out the JSON not in the JS section but direction between the appropriate tags like `<div id="title">Here come the JSON</div>`?

Comment: javascript doesn't have any echo command.. the javascript loads after the page has arrived after rendering into php... So first of all remove all your php code.. and save the pages as php but without <?php ?>

Comment: var content should be defined above there in head... as var content = {}

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server side code, it is only ran on page load - once run, its variables are forgotten and scrapped so yes, you may now think its impossible... well, no.

AJAX uses requests to execute scripts but has a brilliant invention of using a response; we can idolise this later but for now, let's focus on your aim.

```
$('#lang-de').click(function() {
    $.post('index.php' { lang: de })
       .done(function(data) {
       });
});
```

Inside your Index PHP file, you could have a POST controller determining language of the page which can also be caught as a session, ie:

```
if(isset($_POST['lang']) || isset($_SESSION['lang'])):
    // Code to change language
   // Update the Session language
endif;
```

We can use the session so once the language is choosen, we're not requiring on a constant post to each page to know what language to use.

The thing about AJAX is that the respone is gathered by page output, therefore, you can simply just use:

```
<div id="page-container">
```

and then use this inside the `.done` function:

```
$('#page-container').html = data;
```

This will then load all the new language and page into the current one.

Comment: Seems as if he only wants to change the `$lang` var though, which is a JS var. If this is true and he already has all the info he needs loaded into his page, changing the js var through a function is simply a matter of access scope.

Comment: That's what happens when you scan read, you miss interpret the question completely, oh no. Well, although it doesn't directly answer his issue, its a method so I'll leave the answer up for anyone who maybe is searching stackoverflow for a similar idea. Thanks @Wobbles